# JavaScript or Jquery how to split urls in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, url, split

I'm finding it quite hard to split urls in the same string. In the database, I have a few columns which contain either one or many urls and I'm trying to split them up so that I can convert them into images and make them clickable. The problem is, is that they're 3 kind of images jpg, jpeg and png.

[View Multiple URLS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vg8ZN.png)

What i've tried so far:

```js
  function validateImages(imageList) {
    var png = imageList.split('png');
    var jpeg = imageList.split('jpeg');
    var jpg = imageList.split('jpg');
    var all = png + jpeg + jpg;

    var validatedStr = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
        validatedStr += "<a href='" + all[i] + "' target='_blank'><img src='" + all[i] + "' style='width=50px; height: 50px;' /></a>";
    }

    return validatedStr;
  }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give a couple of examples of an input and the desired output?

Comment: Are they separated by new line?

Comment: do you want to extract name.jpg from the url?

Comment: Some urls are seperated by \r\n and some are separated by comma

Comment: split will return array, why do you `+` them this will change it to string ? you probably need concat here. i.e try in console  `[1,2] + [1,2]` and `[1,2].concat([1,2])`

Answer (score 0):

Extract filename which contains either jpg, png, jpeg and add it to the array. Retrieve the first element of the array and you will get the name of the image, You can easily append something onto it or store the values in another array and then loop through them..

```
var myString = "https://www.route.com/path/subpath/image1.jpg https://www.route.com/path/subpath/image2.png";
var myRegexp = /\w+\.(jpg|png|jpeg)/g;

var array1 = []

while ((array1 = myRegexp.exec(myString)) !== null) {
  console.log('Result', array1[0]);

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Some images are separated by \r\n, some are separated by space some not and some are separated by commas... Can't win lol but thanks anyway